# python3 regular expressions looking for 1 or more strings

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am new to Python (using Python3.6). I would like to get a 1 if one or more strings are read in a txt file. Specifically, I have the "read.txt" file, from which I want to get a 1 in my new list "exemptions" if 1 or more strings are met in that file. I have the following code:

```
string1 = 'first sentence I want to check it exists in the read.txt file'
string2 = 'another sentence I want to check it exists in the read.txt file'
exemptions = []

with open('read.txt') as f:
   line2 = f.read()  # read the txt file
   wantedstring = re.findall(string1 | string2, line2)  # find string1 or string2 in line2
   if len(wantedstring) > 0:  # if either string1 or string2 appears
      exemptions.append(1)   # append a 1 to "exemptions"
   else:
      exemptions.append(0)  # otherwise a 0
print(exemptions)
```

However, it seems the re.findall(string1|string2) code does not work (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'). I also tried "re.findall(string1 or string2, line2)" but still does not work.
My desired output would be a [1] if any of the two strings exists in the file, and [0] otherwise.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What you really want is a search using aho-corasick, e.g. by using [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/1.0.0](this).

Comment: @user2722968 Probably a good suggestion but the link doesn't work, also it seems there is a more recent version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by replacing:

```
wantedstring = re.findall(string1 | string2, line2)  # find string1 or string2 in line2
```

To (*`|` is replaced by `+'|'+`*):

```
wantedstring = re.findall(string1 + '|' + string2, line2)  # find string1 or string2 in line2
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much!

Comment: The strings need to be escaped with `re.escape()` for this to work when they contain regular expressions special characters.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you Gribouillis. I tried to put a string1 that did not match any string in the txt file (i.e. string1 = 'asdasdasdasd') and a string2 that did match. The output was still [1] as I wanted. If both strings are matched, the output is still a [1]. Thanks again.

Comment: If you choose `string1 = 'f.o\\war'` and the file contains `foobar`, it will be a false positive. You can build other counter examples with re's special chars such as `.^+*{}[]()` etc. In your question, string1 and string2 are not regular expressions but strings to be matched literally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape regular expression's special characters such as `.` and use string concatenation

```
re.findall(re.escape(string1)+ "|"+re.escape(string2), line2)
```

Comment: Thank you Gribouillis. That also worked but I prefer open-source solution for simplicity. Thanks again anyway!

Comment: It is simpler, but it doesn't work. For example it will report a match for the sentence `first sentence I want to check it exists in the readZtxt file`